# How can I position my autocomplete box under the search box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

Hello I'm trying to create a custom suggestion box for search box. The parent div is flex box and suggestion box is positioned absolute. but the top and left property of css. It is taking of global page and not parent.

```css
.header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
  
  .header li {
    float: right;
  }
  
 .header li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .header{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  
.suggesetionbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.SearchContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

input{
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>logo</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="SearchContainer">
        <input placeholder="Search" class="search" type="text">
        <div class="suggesetionbox">
          <p>item1</p><p>item2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="/login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can see in css "*suggesetionbox*" the top property is targeting complete page not parent div.
Can someone suggest how can I append the div correctly under search box.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: First, add `position: relative` to your `.SearchContainer`. This makes sure that the dropdown is set on the searchcontainer and not on the whole page. Then, the `overflow: hidden` needs to be removed from `.header ul` in order to see the whole dropdown.

Remove the display flex on your suggestionbox class. You can fix the alignment of the options in your topbar with the flex box in your `.header ul`

```css
.header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 25px;
    align-items: center;

  }
  
  .header li {
    float: right;
  }
  
 .header li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .header{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  
.suggesetionbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.SearchContainer {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>logo</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="SearchContainer">
        <input placeholder="Search" class="search" type="text">
        <div class="suggesetionbox">
          <p>item1</p><p>item2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="/login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I tried that, still if we add top and left to the suggestions it'll move with respect to page co-ordinates. I've border radius to input so need it little bit right.

Comment: Please see my editted answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
.SearchContainer {
    position: relative;
    ...
}
```

Comment: with position relative the suggestion box is only visible inside the parent height, which is small

Answer (score 0):

```
.suggesetionbox {
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top: none;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 100%;
        /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    .SearchContainer {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).